# Error when executing PhantomJs procedure - File does not exist or is not executable

Tags: php, phantomjs

Error when executing PhantomJs procedure - File does not exist or is not executable
in centos 7 
and this the php Code

```
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

$client = Client::getInstance();

$client->getEngine()->setPath('bin/phantomjs');

$request  = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest();
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

$request->setMethod('GET');
$request->setUrl('https://www.google.com');

$client->send($request, $response);

if($response->getStatus() === 200) {
    echo $response->getContent();
}
```

Comment: Try to give it the absolute path to the phantomjs, like `/usr/bin/phantomjs`

Comment: same error => File does not exist or is not executable: /usr/bin/phantomjs

Comment: That was just an example. Where is your PhantomJS actually located on the server?

Comment: yes it's working thank you , reinstall it with the real path in composer.json

Answer (score 0):

set the permissions of the folder to 777 worked for me . also get the path of the phantom like this
$client = Client::getInstance();

```
    $client->getEngine()->setPath('/var/www/html/phantomJs/bin/phantomjs');
```

using ubunutu

Comment: According to the comments on the original post, this was resolved 2018. Also, be wary of setting `777` as the permissions as that's almost never what you're looking for. You rather want to figure out which users and or groups are requiring what access and set it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you install PhantomJS globally, you should give absolute path:

> $client->getEngine()->setPath('/home/user/bin/phantomjs');